# Orden de importancia y significado exacto de las palabras que sirven para ordenar el texto de un documento

Tags: gramática, significado, redacción

En español hay multitud de palabras que sirven para encontrar texto dentro de un libro y mejorar su orden y comprensión:

- [Capítulo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7L0XroM). *División que se hace en los libros y en cualquier otro escrito para el mejor orden y más fácil comprensión de la materia.*
- [Párrafo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RybbDeZ). *Fragmento de un texto en prosa constituido por un conjunto de líneas seguidas y caracterizado por el punto y aparte al final de la última.*
- [Epígrafe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FwgdR6j). *Resumen que suele preceder a cada uno de los capítulos u otras divisiones de una obra científica o literaria, o a un discurso o escrito que no tenga tales divisiones.*
- [Apartado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=35tp8q3). *Párrafo o serie de párrafos dentro de un escrito en los que se considera algún asunto por separado.*
- [Título](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zu7EOGZ). *Cada una de las partes principales en que suelen dividirse las leyes, reglamentos, etc., o subdividirse los libros de que constan.*
- ...

Precisamente mirando las definiciones acabo de descubrir que estaba llamando "epígrafe" a lo que en realidad era un "párrafo". En todo caso, entiendo por las definiciones que el orden de mayor a menor importancia (extensión de texto) dentro de una obra sería:

1. Capítulo.
2. Apartado.
3. Párrafo.

quedando "epígrafe" como algo aparte que no sé muy bien como encaja, y "título" como una palabra que parece que solo se usa en determinados ámbitos pero no sé si iría antes o después que "capítulo". El caso es que me da la sensación de que existen más palabras similares, y mi pregunta es: ¿cuáles son esas otras palabras que me faltan, y cómo se ordenan de mayor a menor extensión de texto abarcado? ¿Qué significan exactamente, poniendo ejemplos de libros reales?

Comment: Yo quisiera saber cómo hablar de los bullets y las líneas individuales de las listas numeradas.

Comment: @aparente001 pues eso da perfectamente para otra pregunta, si te animas. :-)

Comment: Parece que incluso [en la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partes_del_libro) hay cierta confusión sobre _epígrafe_: lo ponen en _Páginas finales_ pero luego mencionan _Resumen que precede a cada uno de los capítulos o secciones del libro_.

Comment: No hay una estructura que sirva para todos los textos; es diferente un texto académico, uno periodístico, uno legal, etc., cada uno tiene su estructura particular y luego están los manuales de estilo que entre otras cosas suelen definir la estructura que se debe seguir en los documentos a los que afecta.

Answer (score 3):

La Oficina de Publicaciones de la Unión Europea tiene publicado material de referencia sobre [los nombres de cada elemento](http://publications.europa.eu/code/es/es-120700.htm) y [cómo numerarlos](http://publications.europa.eu/code/es/es-250600.htm).

Según dicha página, la estructura general, creo, es como sigue:

- Partes

  - Títulos

    - Capítulos

      - Secciones

        - Artículos

          - Apartados

            - Letras

Quedaría algo así:

[image: Estructura de una parte]

Si el texto es para modificar un artículo existente, la división es ésta:

- Artículos

  - Puntos

    - (opcional: Artículos)

      - Apartados

        - Letras

          - Incisos
          - Guiones

Imagen explicativa:

[image: Estructura de un artículo]

Sé que esto no responde completamente a tu pregunta, pero es un comienzo. Y así no se queda sin respuesta.

Comment: Es un inicio muy bueno, y te agradezco enormemente el increíble esfuerzo que estás haciendo al responder a todas estas preguntas que se estaban quedando atrás sin respuesta. :-)

Comment: Eso es un manual de estilo para documentos de la UE y  puede servir como referencia para ver la jerarquía de algunas de esas secciones que en general serán similares en diferentes documentos pero otros textos pueden tener una estructura muy diferente.

Comment: Quiero decir  documentos de instituciones de la UE

Comment: Por eso digo que sirve de referencia y para otros tipos de documentos pero no para todos.